# Invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*'(Trying to do recursion with pointers)

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers, recursion

Here is the code.It's taking 3 int in the array input. Then it is passed to the function binary.It converts decimal numbers to binary.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace::std;

void binary(int *);

int main() {
    int input[3];

    cout << "Enter 3 numbers : ";

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++ ){
        cin >> input[i];
    }

    binary(input);


    return 0;
}

void binary(int *num){
    int rem = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ;i < 3; i++){

        if (num[i] < 1){
            cout << rem;
            return;
        }

        rem = num[i] % 2;
        binary(*num / 2);

        cout << rem;
    }
}
```

The problem is on the 4th last line

```
 binary(*num / 2);
```

Here it shows the error => invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]

Help me out !

Comment: What part of the error message you did not understand? The expression `*num / 2` is an integer. The function expects an `int *` as a parameter, and not an `int`.

Comment: How do you expect your function to work if you are passing an int to a function that receives a pointer (in your case, that would probably be an array with 3 integers) ?

Comment: Don't combine loops and recursion.

Comment: `binary(*num / 2);` Think twice. What did you meant to do there actually?

Comment: `binary(*num / 2);` binary takes a pointer to int and you pass to it integer value instead of a pointer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the function `binary()` takes a pointer to int as an argument and in your function body you call it recursively passing `int` value (the value in the address that the pointer points to).

correct your code:

```
num[i] /= 2;
binary(num);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand fully what you're doing in this code, but I can tell you what happened.

1. `*num / 2` works as `(*num) / 2`. `num` is a pointer (it has type `int*`)  that points to the beginning of your array (to the first element). `*num` extracts the value of the first element (it has the type `int`).
2. `(*num) / 2` divides the value of the first element. It returns an integer value.
3. `binary(*num / 2)` - in here you pass the integer value as an argument of the function `binary` that takes `int*` instead of `int`. That leaded to the error.

If you want to divide all elements of the array, you should do it for each element separately. For example:

```
num[0] /= 2;
num[1] /= 2;
num[2] /= 2;

binary(num);
```