# Passing new value to a pointer via a recursive function in c++

Tags: c++, pointers

How I can change the value of `p` to `1` passing it as an argument to a recursive function.
This is my code:

```
class Solution
{
   void g(int n,int k,int *p){
       if(k==0) return;
       if(k%n==0) g(n,k-1,1);
       cout<<p<< endl;
       g(n,k-1,p+1);
   }
   public:
       int josephus(int n, int k)
           { int p=1;
           g(n,k,&p);
           return p;
       }
};
```

I get this errors:

```
prog.cpp: In member function void Solution::g(int, int, int*):
prog.cpp:14:21: error: invalid conversion from int to int* [-fpermissive]
 if(k%n==0) g(n,k-1,1);
                     ^
prog.cpp:12:9: note:   initializing argument 3 of void Solution::g(int, int, int*)
    void g(int n,int k,int *p){
```

Comment: Why do you use pointer?

Comment: try reference. and write some tests.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int\*'(Trying to do recursion with pointers)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41268083/invalid-conversion-from-int-to-inttrying-to-do-recursion-with-pointers)

Comment: @outis Superficially, the question you found asks a similar question in the title. However, the question itself in the post seems unrelated to this problem.

Comment: @jxh: on the contrary, both questions pass an `int` when an `int*` is expected instead of using the pointer to store the result of the integer expression and then passing the pointer. Both questions use the pointer for pass-by-reference, and both are about recursive functions. What differs is the exact expression, but that's not enough to make a question not a duplicate.

Comment: @outis Thanks for the explanation. While I can objectively determine how to modify the code to perform as intended by the OP in this question, I do not see how to do so with the proposed duplicate. The weakness leads one to question whether the accepted solution is really addressing the asked question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says you cannot pass an `int` as a parameter to a function when it expects an `int *`.

There is also a logical bug in your code:

```
       g(n,k-1,p+1);
```

This recursive call increments the pointer value, which makes it point past the passed in object, since the function was called like this:

```
           { int p=1;
           g(n,k,&p);
```

Since your function takes an `int *`, you need to dereference the pointer to manipulate the referenced object.  So, you probably intend to increment `*p` and then make the recursive call:

```
       ++*p;
       g(n,k-1,p);
```

To address the compilation error, you probably intended to assign `1` to the `int` object and make the recursive call.

```
       if(k%n==0) {
           *p = 1;
           g(n,k-1,p);
       }
```

Comment: Wouldn't `++*p` be an `int` not an `int*`?